# *.dbf file reader iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, foxpro

Does anyone knows a iOS library for manage (reading) *.dbf files?
Found a dbf-reader on [github](https://github.com/davbeck/DBF-Reader) but its for MAC OS; any other starting point for this?

Comment: I'd be amazed if there is one - it's not just the DBF but handling indexes and potentially database containers, triggers, sprocs.

You might be better off looking at converting it to SQLite or CSV before it gets onto the phone.